# how does google map determine locations for phones without gps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gps, maps, cellid

http://www.google.com/mobile/maps/

Using this on phones without gps, the locatiosn can be obtained as well.

I am currently using the html5 geocoder/gear for obtaining locations. However this only works for iphone and android. BUt how does google map get the information from phones without this capbility?

Answer (score 1):

It can deduce the location of the phone from the list of towers that are in range of the phone. Each tower has a unique footprint and Google knows the location of them. It is considerably less accurate than GPS, but is still able to give your rough location.

Watch the [video from Google explaining the technology](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6gqipmbcok). The explanation starts at 1:16.

Comment: so my next question would be is it possible to get the cellid in the browser? Also is there a free api to obtain the correct mapping from a cellid?